# How to model class that extends Observable to access state information: Cannot refer to an instance field while explicitly invoking a constructor

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I would like to model an industrial system which consists of a conveyor belt that has a sensor to detect when an object reaches certain position using RxJava.

To simulate the sensor I have a fake class that should receives and object position and increments it with time until it reached the supposed sensor position. Then it would notify it's observers (the conveyor belt):

```
public class FakeBeltPositionSensor extends Observable<Signal>{

    private double objectPosition;
    protected Double sensorPosition;

    public FakeBeltPositionSensor(Double sensorPosition) {
        super( (s) -> {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            objectPosition += 1;
            if(objectPosition == sensorPosition){
                s.onNext(new Signal(Signal.Type.SENSOR_REACHED));
                s.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }

    public Double getSensorPosition() {
        return sensorPosition;
    }

    public void setObjectPosition(double objectPosition){
        this.objectPosition = objectPosition;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that obviously I can't access `double objectPosition` in the class constructor: `Cannot refer to an instance field objectPosition while explicitly invoking a constructor`.

Since extending Observable forces you to implement the Observable->subscriber login in the constructor, how would you model this scenario?

The idea is that `FakeBeltPositionSensor` would run continuosly and be able to use `setObjectPosition` to update the object position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to directly extend `Observable`, unless you really know what you're doing. Here's some other implementation to consider (with `Subject`s):

```java
public class FakeBeltPositionSensor {

    private double objectPosition;
    protected Double sensorPosition;

    // or your Signal type instead of Void
    private Subject<Void, Void> positionSubject = PublishSubject.<Void> create().toSerialized();

    public FakeBeltPositionSensor(Double sensorPosition) {
        this.sensorPosition = sensorPosition;
        initPositionShift();
    }

    private void initPositionShift() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        objectPosition++;
        if (objectPosition == sensorPosition) {
            positionSubject.onNext(null);
            positionSubject.onCompleted();
        }
    }

    public Observable<Void> positionReached() {
        return positionSubject;
    }

    public Double getSensorPosition() {
        return sensorPosition;
    }

    public void setObjectPosition(double objectPosition) {
        this.objectPosition = objectPosition;
    }
}
```

You'll have to adjust it for your case: make the `Subject` relay items of some meaningful type (rather then `Void`), optionally add check for the target position in `setObjectPosition()` (but then make sure you're not trying to call `onNext()` after `onCompleted()`), etc.

To `subscribe` to the changes use `positionReached()`.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. One more question, what's the benefit of using PublishSubject instead of Observable? In addition there should be a getter to access positionSubject and be able to subscribe to it, shouldn't it?

Comment: @WornOutSoles you don't need to instantiate an `Observable` directly with its constructor (it has numerous factory methods for a reason(s)) and you don't need to think of a workaround to initialize instance fields before the call to `super`. Generally, I think this solution could be cleaner and more transparent. As for the getter: `positionReached()` provides access to it and exposes it as a normal `Observable`, you just subscribe to it as you would to `FakeBeltPositionSensor` in your example.